# Getting the exact center of the currently being generated map while generating its chunks

Tags: php, pocketmine

I'm trying to get the center of the map while generating it to know when to set the blocks... (To make a circle of pillars)

There's currently no way that I know that can get the center of the map while its generating chunks...

Any way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "center of the map"?

Comment: center X and Z coordinates

Comment: Isn't that constant?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the center:

```
(x: (1/2) * (max_x - min_x), y: (1/2) * (max_y - min_y), z: (1/2) * (max_z - min_z))
```

Comment: It is + instead of -